# Filling a Table dynamically based on user inputs

Tags: excel, excel-formula

[image]

I want to add the years 2033 2034 2035 and so on until retirement_year+lifeExpectency-currentAge.
All the columns below the year column would be filled by the future value formula of the current expenses.

```html
<style type="text/css">
.tg  {border-collapse:collapse;border-spacing:0;}
.tg td{border-color:black;border-style:solid;border-width:1px;font-family:Arial, sans-serif;font-size:14px;
  overflow:hidden;padding:10px 5px;word-break:normal;}
.tg th{border-color:black;border-style:solid;border-width:1px;font-family:Arial, sans-serif;font-size:14px;
  font-weight:normal;overflow:hidden;padding:10px 5px;word-break:normal;}
.tg .tg-c3ow{border-color:inherit;text-align:center;vertical-align:top}
.tg .tg-0pky{border-color:inherit;text-align:left;vertical-align:top}
</style>
<table class="tg">
<thead>
  <tr>
    <th class="tg-c3ow">Enter   below Values In Green</th>
    <th class="tg-0pky"> </th>
    <th class="tg-0pky"></th>
    <th class="tg-0pky"></th>
    <th class="tg-0pky"></th>
  </tr>
</thead>
<tbody>
  <tr>
    <td class="tg-0pky">Age of   Retirement</td>
    <td class="tg-c3ow">45</td>
    <td class="tg-0pky"></td>
    <td class="tg-0pky"></td>
    <td class="tg-0pky"></td>
  </tr>
  <tr>
    <td class="tg-0pky">Discounted   Rate</td>
    <td class="tg-c3ow">8%</td>
    <td class="tg-0pky"></td>
    <td class="tg-0pky"></td>
    <td class="tg-0pky"></td>
  </tr>
  <tr>
    <td class="tg-0pky">Inflation Rate   Normal</td>
    <td class="tg-c3ow">7%</td>
    <td class="tg-0pky"></td>
    <td class="tg-0pky"></td>
    <td class="tg-0pky"></td>
  </tr>
  <tr>
    <td class="tg-0pky">Inflation Rate   High</td>
    <td class="tg-c3ow">10%</td>
    <td class="tg-0pky"></td>
    <td class="tg-0pky"></td>
    <td class="tg-0pky"></td>
  </tr>
  <tr>
    <td class="tg-0pky">Inflation Rate   Low</td>
    <td class="tg-c3ow">3%</td>
    <td class="tg-0pky"></td>
    <td class="tg-0pky"></td>
    <td class="tg-0pky"></td>
  </tr>
  <tr>
    <td class="tg-0pky">Life   Expectency in years</td>
    <td class="tg-c3ow">90</td>
    <td class="tg-0pky"></td>
    <td class="tg-0pky"></td>
    <td class="tg-0pky"></td>
  </tr>
  <tr>
    <td class="tg-0pky">Current Age</td>
    <td class="tg-c3ow">35</td>
    <td class="tg-0pky"></td>
    <td class="tg-0pky"></td>
    <td class="tg-0pky"></td>
  </tr>
  <tr>
    <td class="tg-0pky">Current Year</td>
    <td class="tg-c3ow">2023</td>
    <td class="tg-0pky"></td>
    <td class="tg-0pky"></td>
    <td class="tg-0pky"></td>
  </tr>
  <tr>
    <td class="tg-0pky">SL.NO</td>
    <td class="tg-0pky">Yearly Expenses at Current date (Standard/Medium   lifestyle)</td>
    <td class="tg-0pky">Expense_now</td>
    <td class="tg-0pky">Inflation</td>
    <td class="tg-0pky">2033</td>
  </tr>
  <tr>
    <td class="tg-0pky">1</td>
    <td class="tg-0pky">OPD   Consultation</td>
    <td class="tg-c3ow">₹ 14,000.00</td>
    <td class="tg-c3ow">6%</td>
    <td class="tg-0pky"> ₹                                    25,071.87   </td>
  </tr>
  <tr>
    <td class="tg-0pky">2</td>
    <td class="tg-0pky">2   Times Health Checkup Senior Citizen package for a couple</td>
    <td class="tg-c3ow">₹ 28,000.00</td>
    <td class="tg-c3ow">8%</td>
    <td class="tg-0pky"> ₹                                    60,449.90   </td>
  </tr>
  <tr>
    <td class="tg-0pky">3</td>
    <td class="tg-0pky">Health   insurance premium (30L Coverage) for a couple</td>
    <td class="tg-c3ow">₹ 65,000.00</td>
    <td class="tg-c3ow">5%</td>
    <td class="tg-0pky"> ₹                                1,05,878.15 </td>
  </tr>
</tbody>
</table>
```

Now I want the table to be dynamic based on the inputs in green. How do i achieve that ?
I tried using sequence to get the year columns but then the formulas do not fill automatically for all the items. I just want to avoid dragging the mouse pointer to fill the table.
how do i add 2034 2035 column automatically and the formulas for sl 1,2,3

Comment: So poste sample as markdown table with expected outcomes and what you tried and where you got stuck. https://www.tablesgenerator.com/markdown_tables